# Rep change table numbers appear to conflict with actual numbers of people with a specific amount of rep change

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

In the rep change table for Stack Overflow it says there have only been 57 users who have achieved more than 500+ rep change, but when I order the lists by total reputation change, there appear to be at least hundreds of users, if not more.

Does anyone know the reason for this apparent incongruity?

Comment: 500 rep change in what time interval?  Week?  A link to the page that is buggy would be helpful.

Comment: If you go to http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2016-04-01/5202687#5202687 you can see the tables. Yet if you click 'Order By: Rank Change' there appear to be loads of us who've climbed that fast that quickly...

Comment: It's only 57 users that had a __5000__ reputation change in the quarter

Comment: So the other list is all users who have ever achieved 5000+ rep change over... a particular period...?

Comment: No it's the number of people achieving 5000+ rep change in the current quarter (Q2 2016)

Comment: Huh? So 'Order By: Rank Change' lists all the people in the current quarter and so does the right-hand rank change table?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  The right hand table is just a summary.  It's two ways of communicating the same data.

Comment: If it's the same data then why does the right had table show 57 users getting over 5000+ rep this quarter, while 'Order By: Rank Change' shows a far greater number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111145/discussion-between-ryanyuyu-and-peter-david-carter).

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter If you order by "rank change", it sorts by peoples' change in *rank* (as in, how they did compared to other people), not their change in *reputation*. The two are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing "Rank Change" with "Reputation Change" in this case.

What you're seeing in the default sort is users ordered by how much reputation they received. In this case, 57 users *this quarter* have gained 5,000 rep or more. This is easily confirmed by finding the rank 57 user for the quarter, and noting they are (currently) the last user with more than 5,000 rep gained this quarter.

Here's where you're getting confused: When you sort by "Rank Change", you're sorting by *how many places they went up or down in the league* since the last quarter. Basically, you're sorting on this column:

[image]

That column isn't the change in *reputation* for the quarter, just the change in their place on the list. In this picture we can see that Stephen Cleary has currently moved up 62 places on the list, and Lightness Races In Orbit has moved up 63 places.

So when you sort on "Rank Change", there are a *lot* more people who have gone up more than 5,000 *places on the leaderboard* than there currently are people who have gained 5,000 *reputation on Stack Overflow* this quarter.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't realise there were that many ranks. I guess I've gone up loads of ranks but it didn't take 'that' much rep to do it. Awesome.